# Touching my fixture fails

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm trying to tap a falling object in my Cocos2d/Box2d app.

Here's my touchesBegan code:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

    for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
        b2Vec2 bPos = b->GetPosition();
        for (b2Fixture *f = b->GetFixtureList(); f; f=f->GetNext()) {

            if (f->TestPoint(locationWorld)) {
                NSLog(@"hit it!");
            }

        }
    }
```

I have 2 objects in my world, the ground and the falling object. I have gravity really slow so touching it shoudn't be a problem. What is odd is that my positions seem off by a lot!

In the last run locationWorld (where I tapped) was:

```
Printing description of locationWorld:
(b2Vec2) locationWorld = {
  x = 7.90625
  y = 9.875
}
```

I went through the outer loop twice, once for each body, and got:

```
Printing description of bPos:
(b2Vec2) bPos = {
  x = 3.03125
  y = 19.6643
}
Printing description of bPos:
(b2Vec2) bPos = {
  x = 8.59375
  y = 17.4969
}
```

What is odd is that the 2nd body, the one reported at (8.59, 17.49) should be the falling object, but the Y coordinate is way off.

This is my first cocos2d/box2d app so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. I've been googling for awhile and this seems like it should work.

Thanks for any help.

**SEE MY ANSWER BELOW, MY CODE HERE IS CORRECT, I'M SETTING UP MY FIXTURES INCORRECTLY.**

Comment: "Touching my fixture fails" <= you sure this is the type of question you want to ask on stackoverflow.com? Made my day! :D

Comment: and your comment made me smile after a very hard day! I'm going to need that tomorrow when I tackle this again. I have the touches working but my world is getting corrupted. Don't have enough info for an answer...

Comment: Still laughing here … :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, this is sorta working now but I'm sure I'll have another question from it.

When I ran this above I had created a fairly small dynamic box so the items would pile up on the ground, overlapping each other.

> dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.25f, .25f)

This was the cause. When I open this up to something much larger, say:

> dynamicBox.SetAsBox((spriteSize.width/PTM_RATIO)/4, (spriteSize.height/PTM_RATIO)/4);

Then it becomes possible with the above code to touch a body. (So my question needs to be remformulated since I do want the objects piling up, overlapping each other.

I also have no idea why I needed to divide the size by 4 to get the items close to each other, that's just plain bothering me.